# objcopy: bloated binary output file

Tags: elf, bootloader, objcopy

While working on my bootloader project, I noticed that the resulting binary file is larger than the sum of the sizes of each section in the original ELF file.

After linking the bootloader image via `ld`, the ELF file is structured as follows:

```
$ readelf -S elfboot.elf 
There are 10 section headers, starting at offset 0xa708:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00007e00 000e00 004bc7 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000c9d0 0059d0 000638 00   A  0   0 32
  [ 3] .initcalls        PROGBITS        0000ec20 007c20 00000c 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 4] .exitcalls        PROGBITS        0000ec30 007c30 00000c 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 5] .data             PROGBITS        0000ec40 007c40 0001e0 00  WA  0   0 32
  [ 6] .bss              NOBITS          0000ee20 007e20 00025c 00  WA  0   0 32
  [ 7] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 007e20 0016e0 10      8 166  4
  [ 8] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 009500 0011bb 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00a6bb 00004a 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  p (processor specific)
```

I noticed that there is a rather big gap (~7KB) between the sections `.rodata` and `.initcalls`. I also checked out the content of each section:

```
$ objdump -s elfboot.elf
[...]
Contents of section .rodata:
[...]
 cfc0 23cf0000 80000000 2fcf0000 00010000  #......./.......
 cfd0 3bcf0000 00020000 47cf0000 00040000  ;.......G.......
 cfe0 54cf0000 00080000 61cf0000 00100000  T.......a.......
 cff0 6ecf0000 00200000 7bcf0000 00400000  n.... ..{....@..
 d000 89cf0000 00800000                    ........        
Contents of section .initcalls:
 ec20 02b50000 6db50000 feac0000           ....m.......    
Contents of section .exitcalls:
[...]
```

My linker script tells to align every section at a 16 byte (0x10) boundary. After

```
objcopy -O binary elfboot.elf elfboot.bin
```

the resulting binary contains a huge chunk of zero filled bytes at offset `0x5200 (0xd000 - 0x7e00)` all the way to offset `0x6e20 (0xec20 - 0x7e00)`. Now that I know where the zero filled bytes come from, how do I remove them? For reference I added the verbose output of the linker step including the linker script used:

```
  i686-elfboot-gcc -o elfboot.elf -T elfboot.ld    ./src/arch/x86/bootstrap.o ./src/arch/x86/a20.o ./src/arch/x86/bda.o ./src/arch/x86/bios.o ./src/arch/x86/copy.o ./src/arch/x86/e820.o ./src/arch/x86/entry.o ./src/arch/x86/idt.o ./src/arch/x86/realmode_jmp.o ./src/arch/x86/setup.o ./src/arch/x86/opmode.o ./src/arch/x86/pic.o ./src/arch/x86/ptrace.o ./src/arch/x86/video.o ./src/core/bdev.o ./src/core/cdev.o ./src/core/elf.o ./src/core/input.o ./src/core/interrupt.o ./src/core/loader.o ./src/core/main.o ./src/core/module.o ./src/core/pci.o ./src/core/printf.o ./src/core/string.o ./src/core/symbol.o ./src/crypto/crc32.o     ./src/drivers/ide/ide.o  ./src/fs/fs.o ./src/fs/file.o ./src/fs/super.o ./src/fs/ramfs/ramfs.o ./src/fs/isofs/isofs.o  ./src/lib/ata/libata.o ./src/lib/tmg/libtmg.o  ./src/mm/memblock.o ./src/mm/page_alloc.o ./src/mm/slub.o ./src/mm/util.o -O2 -Wl,--verbose -nostdlib -lgcc
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1
  Supported emulations:
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
opened script file elfboot.ld
using external linker script:
==================================================
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(_arch_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /*
     * The boot stack starts at 0x6000 and grows towards lower addresses.
     * The stack is designed to be only one page in size, which should be
     * sufficient for the bootstrap stage.
     */

    . = 0x6000;
    __stack_start = .;

    /*
     * Buffer for reading files from the boot device. Usually boot devices
     * are designed to read data in chunks of 0x200 (512) or 0x800 (2048)
     * bytes. The buffer is large enough to read 4 512 or 2 2048 chunks of
     * data from the disk.
     */

    __buffer_start = .;

    . = 0x7000;
    __buffer_end = .;

    /*
     * Actual bootstrap stage code and data.
     */

    . = 0x7E00;
    __bootstrap_start = .;

    .text ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __text_start = .;
        *(.text*)
        __text_end = .;
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __rodata_start = .;
        *(.rodata*)
        __rodata_end = .;
    }

    /*
     * This section is dedicated to all built-in modules. If a module will
     * be included in the elfboot binary, the module_init function pointer
     * of that module is placed in this section.
     *
     * Make sure to initialize built-in filesystems first as we need it to
     * setup the root file system node.
     */

    .initcalls ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __initcalls_vfs_start = .;

        /* Built-in file systems */
        *(.initcalls_vfs*)

        __initcalls_vfs_end = .;
        __initcalls_dev_start = .;

        /* Built-in devices */
        *(.initcalls_dev*)

        __initcalls_dev_end = .;
        __initcalls_start = .;

        /* Built-in modules */
        *(.initcalls*)

        __initcalls_end = .;
    }

    .exitcalls ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __exitcalls_start = .;
        *(.exitcalls*)
        __exitcalls_end = .;
    }

    .data ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __data_start = .;
        *(.data*)
        __data_end = .;
    }

    .bss ALIGN(0x10) : {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.bss*)
        __bss_end = .;
    }

    __bootstrap_end = .;
}

==================================================
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/bootstrap.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/bootstrap.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/a20.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/a20.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/bda.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/bda.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/bios.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/bios.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/copy.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/copy.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/e820.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/e820.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/entry.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/entry.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/idt.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/idt.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/realmode_jmp.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/realmode_jmp.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/setup.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/setup.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/opmode.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/opmode.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/pic.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/pic.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/ptrace.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/ptrace.o
attempt to open ./src/arch/x86/video.o succeeded
./src/arch/x86/video.o
attempt to open ./src/core/bdev.o succeeded
./src/core/bdev.o
attempt to open ./src/core/cdev.o succeeded
./src/core/cdev.o
attempt to open ./src/core/elf.o succeeded
./src/core/elf.o
attempt to open ./src/core/input.o succeeded
./src/core/input.o
attempt to open ./src/core/interrupt.o succeeded
./src/core/interrupt.o
attempt to open ./src/core/loader.o succeeded
./src/core/loader.o
attempt to open ./src/core/main.o succeeded
./src/core/main.o
attempt to open ./src/core/module.o succeeded
./src/core/module.o
attempt to open ./src/core/pci.o succeeded
./src/core/pci.o
attempt to open ./src/core/printf.o succeeded
./src/core/printf.o
attempt to open ./src/core/string.o succeeded
./src/core/string.o
attempt to open ./src/core/symbol.o succeeded
./src/core/symbol.o
attempt to open ./src/crypto/crc32.o succeeded
./src/crypto/crc32.o
attempt to open ./src/drivers/ide/ide.o succeeded
./src/drivers/ide/ide.o
attempt to open ./src/fs/fs.o succeeded
./src/fs/fs.o
attempt to open ./src/fs/file.o succeeded
./src/fs/file.o
attempt to open ./src/fs/super.o succeeded
./src/fs/super.o
attempt to open ./src/fs/ramfs/ramfs.o succeeded
./src/fs/ramfs/ramfs.o
attempt to open ./src/fs/isofs/isofs.o succeeded
./src/fs/isofs/isofs.o
attempt to open ./src/lib/ata/libata.o succeeded
./src/lib/ata/libata.o
attempt to open ./src/lib/tmg/libtmg.o succeeded
./src/lib/tmg/libtmg.o
attempt to open ./src/mm/memblock.o succeeded
./src/mm/memblock.o
attempt to open ./src/mm/page_alloc.o succeeded
./src/mm/page_alloc.o
attempt to open ./src/mm/slub.o succeeded
./src/mm/slub.o
attempt to open ./src/mm/util.o succeeded
./src/mm/util.o
attempt to open /home/croemheld/Repositories/elfboot/elfboot-toolchain/lib/gcc/i686-elfboot/8.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/croemheld/Repositories/elfboot/elfboot-toolchain/lib/gcc/i686-elfboot/8.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
(/home/croemheld/Repositories/elfboot/elfboot-toolchain/lib/gcc/i686-elfboot/8.2.0/libgcc.a)_umoddi3.o
(/home/croemheld/Repositories/elfboot/elfboot-toolchain/lib/gcc/i686-elfboot/8.2.0/libgcc.a)_udivmoddi4.o
```

**Please** note that I am not able to load the sections individually into memory, since my first stage bootloader (boot sector) simply loads the entire file at a specified offset from the boot device. To reduce the size of the second stage bootloader image, I want to try to remove the gap at link time or also if possible at all, at post link time (objcopy, ...).

Comment: I would suggest attaching the linker script to the question, as that is a likely culprit in situations like these.

Comment: @ChrisSmeele Added the entire verbose output of the linker step including the linker script used.

Comment: I'm not certain enough to post an answer, but my hunch is that the difference in writability between .rodata and .initcalls is causing ld to align (sort-of?) the next section. Perhaps try adding `--omagic` to the linker flags?

Comment: @ChrisSmeele I tried experimenting with the linker script and it turns out that when moving the `.rodata` section to the end of the file, the padding completely disappears.

Comment: I know you gave us the readelf output but can you add the output of `objdump -x elfboot.elf` to your question.